# Syntax highlighting: initialization and finalization are not recognized as reserved words in the delphi formatter

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

In the Delphi syntax-highlighter `finalization`, `initialization` and others are not marked as reserved words.

Here's a list of reserved words that do not highlight ok *(with two ok keywords thown in to highlight the difference)*.

```pascal
implementation    //highlight ok
asm               //ok
dispinterface     {not ok}
inherited         {not ok}
library           {not ok}
resourcestring    {not ok}
threadvar         {not ok}
is                (*not ok*)
initialization    //not ok
finalization      {not ok}
end.              //ok
```

Also the highlighter should not highlight inline comments, so `//not ok` should mark the whole comment in light gray.
Note that the `{..}` and `(*..*)` comments work ok.

For completeness where's how the directives are highlighted.
These should also be marked as reserved words, but very few are.

```pascal
absolute          //ok
export
name
public
stdcall
abstract
external          //ok
near
published
strict
assembler         //ok
far
nodefault
read
stored
automated
final
operator
readonly
unsafe
cdecl
forward           //ok
out
reference
varargs
contains
helper
overload
register
virtual           //ok
default
implements
override
reintroduce
winapi
delayed1
index
package
requires
write
deprecated
inline            //ok
pascal
resident
writeonly
dispid
library
platform
safecall
dynamic
local
private
sealed
experimental
message
protected
static
```

Comment: Delphi uses the `lang-pascal` prettifier and I don't see a specific extension for Delphi [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/158100) so I expect you either have to submit a bug at Google Prettify or an FR to create a specific extension for Delhi where it is up to SE if and when they include that on the site.

Comment: The pascal prettifier accepts object-pascal keywords like `class` etc etc, the only implementations that use these keywords are `delphi` and `fpc`, and both implementations have the same set of reserved words. So it's not a FR, it's a bug.

Comment: Sure, your bug report is fine but do know that this needs to fixed in the Google Prettify library first and once done an SE Dev will pull, merge and re-deploy. I'm not sure if the Google Prettify committers watch this tag and open bug reports in their repo based on posts here.

Comment: I've submitted a pull request with these changes, see: https://github.com/google/code-prettify/pull/441